# Help breaking down this sentence: 配役も、今やったので良かったと思う

Tags: translation, phrases, sentence

Context:

Rui:
それで——みんな、(ショーは）どうだい？
軽くとおしてやってみたけれど

Tsukasa:
うむ！　申し分ないと思うぞ！
シチュエーションも場所に合っているしな

Nene:
配役も、今やったので良かったと思う

---

I can understand each word's meaning, but I'm a little confused as to what to make of the sentence. I get that Nene is adding to what Tsukasa said by mentioning the casting, but it's that last bit that confuses me. Is she saying that this play is a good idea because of the casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 配役も、今やった**の**で良かったと思う

The の is a (formal) noun, or (形式)名詞. You can rephrase 今やったの as 今やった**もの**, literally "the one that (we) just did". (Using の sounds more colloquial than using もの.)

To break it down to smaller chunks,

配役も、 -- Also speaking of the casting,
今やったの -- the one that we just did
～でよかった -- was fine
と思う -- I think